# Jetpack Compose: run enter and exit transitions sequentially in AnimatedContent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

When customizing the transition of the `AnimatedContent` composable, one may use the function `togetherWith` that runs both enter and exit transitions simultaneously.

```
AnimatedContent(
    targetState = animationState,
    transitionSpec = {
        fadeIn(tween(durationMillis = FadeInMillis, easing = LinearEasing)) togetherWith
            fadeOut(tween(durationMillis = FadeOutMillis, easing = LinearEasing))
    }
) { targetState ->
    ...
}
```

However, I would like to run the transitions sequentially, i.e. fade in a target state after an initial state completely faded out. How can one do that?

Comment: I think you can chain transitions using `+` (the `plus` operator function)

Comment: No it also do the transitions simultaneously. Here is the doc explanation for it: `Combines different enter transitions. The order of the EnterTransitions being combined does not matter, as these EnterTransitions will start simultaneously.`